# Get values form JsonElement. Convert into multiple Arrays

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

So I want to convert a JsonElement into multiple or one big Array. Im not really sure whats the right idea. Sadly, I dont even know how to start. Maybe some one could help me out. Why do I even need the Pojo Class if need to convert the JsonElement myself. I would be glad if someone could point out my problems.

Api Response:

```
{
    "1": {
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "cap": "188545805889",
        "change": {
            "hour": "1.57",
            "day": "-2.97"
        },
        "price": "11203.9",
        "coinheat": 73,
        "url": "https://chasing-coins.com/coin/BTC"
    },
    "2": {
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "cap": "102905943936",
        "change": {
            "hour": "1.3",
            "day": "-1.23"
        },
        "price": "1058.34",
        "coinheat": 73,
        "url": "https://chasing-coins.com/coin/ETH"
    },
    "3": {
        "symbol": "XRP",
        "cap": "46820128001.0",
        "change": {
            "hour": "0.82",
            "day": "-8.28"
        },
        "price": "1.2086",
        "coinheat": 82,
        "url": "https://chasing-coins.com/coin/XRP"
    }
}
```

Pojo class :

```
public class Coinstats {

    @SerializedName("symbol")
    @Expose
    private String symbol;
    @SerializedName("cap")
    @Expose
    private String cap;
    @SerializedName("change")
    @Expose
    private Change change;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("coinheat")
    @Expose
    private Integer coinheat;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getCap() {
        return cap;
    }

    public void setCap(String cap) {
        this.cap = cap;
    }

    public Change getChange() {
        return change;
    }

    public void setChange(Change change) {
        this.change = change;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getCoinheat() {
        return coinheat;
    }

    public void setCoinheat(Integer coinheat) {
        this.coinheat = coinheat;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

Call :
 c

```
all2.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {

                JsonObject object = response.body().getAsJsonObject();


            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w("no Stats", t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you want response to be converted into List<Coinstats>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you should be able to parse the API response. Please be aware that when the API response changes this code will probably not work.

Description: open the json String into an `JSONObject` and then iterate through the `keys` with an `Iterator` and create new `JSONObject` as needed. 
I load the coin data into a new `CoinData` object and pack them into an `ArrayList`.

Call this method after you have downloaded the json string from your API source.

```
private ArrayList<CoinData> getCoinData(String jsonString){
    ArrayList<CoinData> list = null;

    try {
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        Iterator<String> it = json.keys();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            String p = it.next();
            JSONObject o = json.getJSONObject(p);
            String symbol = o.optString("symbol", "symbol");
            String cap = o.optString("cap", "cap");
            String price = o.optString("price", "price");
            String coinheat = o.optString("coinheat", "coinheat");
            String url = o.optString("url", "url");
            JSONObject change = o.getJSONObject("change");
            String hour = change.optString("hour", "hour");
            String day = change.optString("day", "day");

            Log.e(TAG, "keys = " + p);
            Log.e(TAG, "symbol = " + symbol + " cap = " + cap + " hour = " + hour + "  day = " + day);

            CoinData data = new CoinData();
            data.setCap(cap);
            data.setCoinheat(coinheat);
            data.setDay(day);
            data.setHour(hour);
            data.setPrice(price);
            data.setSymbol(symbol);
            data.setUrl(url);
            list.add(data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "getCoinData  ----  " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Now create a new class—lets call it `CoinData` with its public getters and setters you can access the data and store the coin data in a list object.

```
public class CoinData {

    private static final String TAG = CoinData.class.getSimpleName();

    String symbol = "";
    String cap = "";
    String price = "";

    String coinheat = "";
    String url = "";
    String hour = "";
    String day = "";


    public void setCap(String cap) { this.cap = cap; }
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) { this.symbol = symbol; }
    public void setPrice(String price) { this.price = price; }
    public void setCoinheat(String coinheat) { this.coinheat = coinheat; }
    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
    public void setDay(String day) { this.day = day; }
    public void setHour(String hour) { this.hour = hour; }

    public String getCap() { return this.cap; }
    public String getSymbol() { return this.symbol; }
    public String getPrice() { return this.price; }
    public String getCoinheat() { return this.coinheat; }
    public String getUrl() { return this.url; }
    public String getHour() { return this.hour; }
    public String getDay() { return this.day; }

}
```

!! Later when you are handing the data over to your `RecyclerView` you will only have to pass the `ArrayList<CoinData>` and in your `onBindViewHolder` method use the public getters for the `CoinData`!!

```
ArrayList <CoinData> mCoinData;
public MyAdapter(ArrayList <CoinData> coinData) {
    this.mCoinData = coinData;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
 public MyAdapter(ArrayList <String> coin,ArrayList <String> cap,ArrayList <String> price,ArrayList <String> day) {
```

Which will make your code much more flexible and easier to handle.

Comment: I have fully adapted to your code. Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Networking Library

https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

on response you can create JsonObject

`JSONObject currency = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONArray lisOfcur = currency.getJSONArray("list_of_cur");`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Retrofit when you have to parse JSON manually instead of this you can use Volley, If you want JSON object within JSON object do something like this, if you want hour and day as well on the list then you POJO class must contain a getter and setter for array list of another POJO type which may namely Time.

```
@SerializedName("change")
@Expose
private ArrayList<Time> time;
```

and you have to make getter and setter as well, your list items will contain a list of time. But in every JSON objects contain a single object of "change" so you don't need to create array list, You have to just make getter setter for Time.

```
@SerializedName("change")
@Expose
private Time time;
```